# Change where jQuery UI drag helper is appended to document

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a drag element which is inside a "popout" so when the drag initiates and the user moves away the "popout" hides itself (this is the desired functionality), however, because the helper function that I have set up to return my custom helper appends the helper right after the drag element it also hides when the popout closes.

In summary my question is; can I change where in the document a jQuery UI custom helper is appended to the document?

Comment: can u post some codes so we get a better understanding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the `appendTo` option in the jQuery UI docs, well what it related to anyway!

Since diving into the ui source I found this line:

```
helper.appendTo((o.appendTo == 'parent' ? this.element[0].parentNode : o.appendTo));
```

Which pointed me in the right direction